# Stata14 "proper" case conversion issue

Tags: stata, data-conversion

I am using Stata14. The command:

```
replace name = proper(name)
```

turns "james" into "James". However, the command does not work correctly when the name has a special accented character: the first letter is correctly capitalized but the letter following the special character is also capitalized. For example "rivière" becomes "**R**iviè**R**e".

How can I get round this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True in Stata 15 too but there at least the help at `strproper()` gives advice. See https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?strproper()

Consider

```
. di proper("rivière")
RivièRe

. di ustrtitle("rivière")
Rivière
```

For completeness I also note

```
. di upper(substr("rivière", 1, 1)) + substr("rivière", 2, .)
Rivière
```